Timer with AppLifecycleListener and Cubit not work
I have a timer which decrease the value via Timer.periodic. I can not restart it when I return back to my app.

I have a timer via timer.periodic runing in a cubit. It starts when
I start the app. I put into the Blocprovider the starting function
from the cubit. (Work)


return BlocProvider<PlayerEnergyCubit>(
    create: (context) =>
        PlayerEnergyCubit()..calculateinitialrecoverytime(),
    child: menuHud());   



I listen if the app is in background or foreground via
AppLifecycleListener. That also work, i have different app states
(here paused and resume). (Work)


_listener = AppLifecycleListener(
  onStateChange: _handleStateChange,
);
if (_state != null) {
  _states.add(_state!.name);
}



If the app goes to background I stop the timer via change of a global variable (Work)


{settings.appstatus = 'paused';}


When the app is in the foreground i start the timer again via (Work)


settings.appstatus = 'resumed';
if (context.mounted) {
  context.read<PlayerEnergyCubit>().calculateinitialrecoverytime();
}   



My text widget where i show the global variable should show the updated text (Not work)

The timer starts because I can see it in the console, because i print the timer tick there. But the widget not show the updated value from my global variable. I know that it is correctly updated because when i do hotreload i see the updated variable there. The issue is: When i hot restart the app then the timer and text widget work properly, but when i pause the app and resume from background timer works but not updating text widget

How you are trying to update the widget?
